# Listing available chat rooms in XMPP connection

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

May I know how to list all the available chat rooms (already created) for a particular XMPP connection and user using Smack-Java.  That is, I want the solution as shown below :

room1@conference.localhost.com
room2@conference.localhost.com
.
.
.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without plugins, you basically need to retrive all the services available on your server and then the jid (be carefull: if a groupchat it's private, you'll not be able to retrive in the list)

```
String groupchatHosted = ""; 

for (String service : MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor( connection ).getServiceNames();)
{  
   List<HostedRoom> hosted = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor( connection ).getHostedRooms( service  ));

      for (HostedRoom room : hosted)
     {
       groupchatHosted += room.getJid() + " ";
     }
   }
```

You'll obtain your string with all services (or just use a List of String or another Collection)